# flask - send_file with lazy loading

Tags: python, flask, lazy-loading

i have a huge table (80k rows) with an image in each row. i want to lazy load the images while scrolling. The images are stored in a directory outside flask, so i have to use send_file. this is my python code:

```
@app.route('/getLogImage/')
def getLogImage():
    fileName = request.args.get('fn', None)
    return send_file("D:/images/" + fileName, mimetype='image/jpg')
```

and this is the code of my table:

```
<div class="scrollable-table" style="height:72vh; width:90vw; overflow:scroll;">
<table id="logTable" class="table">
     <thead class="sticky-top" style="background-color: #f8f9fa;">
      <tr>
        <th>Date and time</th>
        <th>Image</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for id in imgids %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ dateTime[loop.index - 1] }}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#imageModal{{ id }}">
                    <img src="{{ url_for('getLogImage', fn=id.zfill(12) ~ '.jpg') }}" class="lazy rounded" width="100px" height="100px">
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

This is the script for lazy loading:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='js/lazyload.js') }}"> 
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Initialize lazy load
    $("img.lazy").lazyload();
  
    // Load more images on scroll
    $('.scrollable-table').scroll(function() {
      $("img.lazy").lazyload();
    });
  });
</script>
```

The problem I am facing is that instead of lazy loading the images it loads them all right away, and that causes long loading times and the cpu to be quite busy. how can i lazy load the images in flask while scrolling along the table?

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem.

```
<img src="{{ url_for('getLogImage', fn=id.zfill(12) ~ '.jpg') }}" class="lazy rounded" width="100px" height="100px">
```

is supposed to be

```
<img data-src="{{ url_for('getLogImage', fn=id.zfill(12) ~ '.jpg') }}" class="lazy rounded" width="100px" height="100px">
```

so the src property should be data-src